# Is it possible to link directories in git?

Tags: git, version-control, cross-platform

I will start with a simplified example describing my intent.

I have a repository `my-rep.git` containing two directories, `src` and deploy. In `src` I have my source code (NodeJS code, but that doesn't matter), and in deploy I want to keep my deploy configuration.
So for example if I have a project, `projectA`, then the structure should look like this,

```
my-rep.git/src/projectA
my-rep.git/deploy/projectA/dotcloud.yml
my-rep.git/deploy/projectA/src
```

Now to my question. I want the source code in `projectA` to be available in the deploy directory for dotcloud. Is there any way I can make `my-rep.git/deploy/projectA/src` point to `my-rep.git/src/projectA`, that is, so when I do a git pull in deploy it will automatically pull the `my-rep.git/deploy/projectA/src`.

It must be supported in git, symbolic linux links won't work as some developers in my team work in Windows.

Comment: what's the relationship between `/src/` and `/deploy/projectA/src/`? Do you even need both, or could the source just live in the latter?

Comment: Well, right now we are trying out different cloud hosting services for the same code base, so eventually we will have deploy/dotcloud, deploy/heroku, deploy/whatever, so in these cases they should all have references to the same code base, that is src -> projectA.
It would have been great if a developer just can go to any of these directories and run the deploy scripts provided by each cloud host.

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat the structure. Use a deploy script instead. If you include the config in your source, abstract it so it doesn't work anywhere. Then rely on smudge/clean scripts that vary with environment to alter the files when checked out and vice-versa.

Comment: The problem is that in my team we work in different environments, Window and Mac OS, and I don't want scripts on different platforms. It should be sufficient for all my team members to just use heroku or dotcloud deploy scripts, no additional scripts or dependencies should be needed. Maybe my vision isn't possible, time will tell :)

Comment: The scripts can be run on either platform. MSysGit works fine for executing bash scripts. I'm sure they work just as well on Mac.

Comment: I will have a look at that. Right now though it feels like I am trying to use git wrong. I probably should look at having one project per git repo and maybe use submodules instead.

Comment: it's perfectly fine and bash is a great way to get things to work on all 3 platforms.